# Как передать mapFragment из Activity в Service?

Tags: java, android

Есть MainActivity, в котором используется карта:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap map;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        startService(new Intent(this, TrackerService.class));
    }
}
```

Как передать/использовать этот же mapFragment, только в Service ?

Comment: его незачем использовать в сервисе. Сервис не должен работать с View. У вас проблемы с архитектурой...

Comment: @metalurgus, ок, методы можно же использовать из MainActivity?

Comment: @metalurgus Думаю, не только не должен, но и не сможет - без путних костылей, по крайней мере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сервис- это служба для выполнения фоновых задач, она не имеет доступа к UI, по крайней мере - легального доступа. Передавать фрагмент в сервис по этой причине нет никакой надобности.